# Where does a file copy to when I scp it?

Tags: scripts, scp

i have this file myfirst.txt located on a cluster of computers down the hall, i.e.:

```
myname@login1:~> ls
myfirst.txt
```

which i want to download to the home directory:

```
scp myname@login1.imbig.cc.mycoll.zz:myfirst.txt .
```

to which i get:

```
myfirst.txt                                   100% 1828     1.8KB/s   00:00
```

now where (on my home computer) is this myfirst.txt file ? i can't find it.  It's not visible when i click 'show hidden files' either.

Tia,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the current directory. To check you should be able to just do:

```
ls
```

Make a note of the directory and it's contents. If the file isn't there, then it's not copied. Make sure you don't have more arguments in that command.

If you have a desktop, this sort of thing can be done via the desktop gui too. You simply mount the ssh server as an sftp from `Places > Connect to Server`

Answer (score 3):

```
scp myname@login1.imbig.cc.mycoll.zz:myfirst.txt .
```

Here you are running `scp` with two arguments. The first is the source, a remote file: `myname@login1.imbig.cc.mycoll.zz:myfirst.txt`. The last argument is the destination. In your case: `.`. `.` is the current directory, so the file will end up in your current directory.

If you want it to go somewhere else, then specify another directory, e.g.

```
scp myname@login1.imbig.cc.mycoll.zz:myfirst.txt /tmp
```

This will copy it to /tmp

You can also specify a new name for it. E.g.

```
scp myname@login1.imbig.cc.mycoll.zz:myfirst.txt /tmp/info.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake that caused this problem.

Make sure you aren't already logged into the remote system using SSH, or else will just copy the files back onto your remote system.